# What have I done wrong here?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I've tried this many times but I can't figure out what's wrong! Please help me to solve this error.

```
#include <`stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  float accum = 0, number = 0;
  char oper;

  printf("\nHello. This is a simple 'printing' calculator. Simply enter the number followed");
  printf(" by the operator that you wish to use. ");
  printf("It is possible to use the standard \noperators ( +, -, *, / ) as well as two extra ");
  printf("operators:\n");
  printf("1) S, which sets the accumulator; and\n");
  printf("2) N, that ends  the calculation (N.B. Must place a zero before N). \n");

  do
  {
    printf("\nPlease enter a number and an operator: ");
    scanf("%f %c", &number, &oper);
    if (number == 0 && oper == 'N')
    {
      printf("Total = %f", accum);
      printf("\nEnd of calculations.");
    }
    else if (oper == '+', '-', '*', '/', 'S')
    {
      switch (oper)
      {
        case 'S':
          accum = number;
          printf("= %f", accum);
          break;
        case '+':
          accum = accum + number;
          printf("= %f", accum);
          break;
        case '-':
          accum = accum - number;
          printf("= %f", accum);
          break;
        case '*':
          accum = accum * number;
          printf("= %f", accum);
          break;
        case '/':
          if (number != 0)
          {
            accum = accum / number;
            printf("= %f", accum);
          }
          else
            printf("Cannot divide by zero.");
          break;
        default:
          printf("Error. Please ensure you enter a correct number and operator.");
          break;
      }
    }
    else
      printf("Error. Please ensure you enter a correct number and operator.");
  }
  while (oper != 'N');
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile this code I get the following error as in the snapshot image here.
[snapshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSjbK.jpg)

Comment: check the very first line #include <`stdio.h>

Comment: Please copy-paste the compiler output, using images for text is very annoying and brittle (I can't access the image due to some redirection failure).

Comment: `==` operator is not an hypotetical `any_of_these()` function. `if (oper == '+', '-', '*', '/', 'S')` is wrong, you **may** rewrite it as `if (oper == '+' || oper == '-' || oper == '*')`but because you already have a `switch` construct you may drop that in favor of `default` block. Note that your error message _"Error. Please ensure you enter..."_ is actually never shown...

Comment: You could use `if (strchr("+-*/S", oper))` instead of `if (oper == '+', '-', '*', '/', 'S')`. Or even just drop the whole `if`-clause, as it does the same as the `switch`'s `default` branch.

Comment: What did you expect `(oper == '+', '-', '*', '/', 'S')` to do?

Comment: Do not post external links or images in general. Site rules require all relevant information **in** the question, unless this is not possible.

Comment: Thank you very much for the support. Finally, got it right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the rules for the `,`-operator this

```
if (oper == '+', '-', '*', '/', 'S')
```

is the same as this

```
if ('-', '*', '/', 'S')
```

is the same as this

```
if ('*', '/', 'S')
```

is the same as this

```
if ('/', 'S')
```

is the same as this

```
if ('S')
```

which is not equal `0` and though is always "*true*".

From the [C11 Standard (draft)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.17p2):

> **6.5.17 Comma operator**
>
> [...]
>
> **Semantics**
>
> **2** The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void expression; there is a
>   sequence point between its evaluation and that of the right operand. Then the right
>   operand is evaluated; the result has its type and value.

Answer (score 3):

First, be cautious about your inclusion :

```
#include <`stdio.h>
```

should be

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Furthermore, you can't use the if-keyword the way you did :

```
if (oper == '+', '-', '*', '/', 'S')
```

should be :

```
if (oper == '+' || oper =='-' || oper == '*' || oper == '/' || oper ==  'S')
```